# C# Split String and Use in If Statement

Tags: c#, string, if-statement

Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this.

I have a string, where I would like to split and use individually in an if statement. For example:

```
string people = "John;Joe;Jane;Mike";
string[] names = people.Split(';');

if(person == "John" || person == "Joe" || person == "Jane" || person == "Mike")
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

There's a better way of doing this, I guess.

Thanks.

Comment: just found this, and it probably would work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501194/c-is-string-in-array

Comment: Be careful...some people will read elegant and think non-readable...

Comment: Yes, use the accepted answer from that question (the `IEnumerable<string>.Contains` method on `string[]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string people = "John;Joe;Jane;Mike";
List<string> names = new List<string>(people.Split(';'));

if(names.Contains(person))
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

Collections are your friends :)

Comment: Using a string array, which is a collection seems efficient enough to me.

Comment: @contactmatt: Arrays are not actually collections, they just happens to have a set of extension methods defined that let you treat them like one (a fact I learned when everyone else posted their answers ;). In this case, sticking with the array would probably suffice, but in many real-world situations, you want the dynamically expanding `List` instead.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(names.Contains(person)) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string people = "John;Joe;Jane;Mike";
string[] names = people.Split(';');

if(names.Contains(person))
{
    ....
}
else
{
    ....
}
```

`Contains<T>` is an extension method of `IEnumerable<T>` (and an array is an `IEnumerable<T>`) so you can use it on the result of `Split` to check if it contains the string you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This would do it:

```
if(names.Contains(person))
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
string people = ";John;Joe;Jane;Mike;"; 
string findPerson = "Joe";

if (people.contains(String.Format(";{0};", findPerson)) {
  ... it's found...
} else {
  ... it's not found ....
}
```

note that I added the delimiters to the beginning and ending of the original string.  Also, we're appending the delimiters to the beginning and end of the findPerson variable.  This ensures that we don't hit on a partial match.  For example finding "chris" in "christoph"