# Determine if list of strings is in another list of strings

Tags: c#, linq

I have two

```
List<string>

l1 = {"one", "two","three","four"}
l2 = {"one", "three"}
```

I want to know if all of l2 is inside l1 as a bool?

Comment: tons of duplicate

Comment: ... and it's not a question. It's a request. What have you tried so far?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy on IEnumerable<T>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby-on-ienumerablet)

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Is String in Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/501194/c-sharp-is-string-in-array)

Comment: Off topic? Closed as off topic? What is going on in this place? Do we not answer questions any more?

Comment: @jason this is a poorly asked question that shows no effort to find a solution, and is a likely duplicate. But you are correct that it is on topic.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: I would agree with all of that. But this: "poorly asked question" *and* "that shows no effort to find a solution" are unfortunately *both* true for a very large fraction of the questions that I stumble upon on this site.

Comment: Two questions are linked as possible duplicates of this one. It is not the case that this question is a duplicate of either of those. Additionally, the accepted answer in those questions should not be used to establish an answer for this question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
var allIn = !l2.Except(l1).Any();
```

Answer (score 9):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except.aspx):

```
var contained = !l2.Except(l1).Any();
```

Note that several people have proposed the following:

```
var contained = l2.All(x => l1.Contains(x));
```

Let me explain why this is *not* the best solution, and *should* be avoided.

The main reason is because it's slower. It's slower because for every item in `l2`, it does a *linear* scan through `l1`, over and over for *every* item in `l2`. Let `m` be the length of `l1` and `n` be the length of `l2`. So that's a scan through `m` items, done `n` times. Thus, total cost is `O(m * n)`. The alternative would build two hash tables with `O(1)` amortized lookup. Building the hash tables is `O(m)` and `O(n)` respectively. Then, for each of `n` items, check if the item is in the hash table. That's `O(n)`, amortized. Thus, total cost is `O(m + n)`.

Answer (score -1):

here you go

```
 bool b = l2.All( s => l1.Contains(s));
```

Comment: This will be slower than the alternatives. That is, it's like `O(m * n)` or something, instead of `O(m + n)` (here `m` and `n` are the lengths of the lists).

Comment: @Jason: Perhaps this is true. Why not explain why it is slower? That'd be quite instructive.

Comment: @stakx: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17980423/45914), I've edited in a response.