# Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' on aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #ddd; width: 100%; text-align: center; height: 130px">
    <asp:ImageButton 
        ID="imgDigitalDoc" 
        Width="100%" 
        Height="130px" 
        runat="server" 
        ImageUrl='<%# Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || "pdfFormat.png" ? "~/PocketData/Temp/" + Eval("PatID") + "/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("DocumentFileName")) : "~/assets/img/" + Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath")) %>' 
        ToolTip="View" 
        OnClick="imgDigitalDocOpen_Click" 
    />
</div>
```

Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'string' on aspx page

Comment: My suggestion would be to move all that logic into a public method on your aspx page and then call the method. That way you will be able to lean on the compiler for guidance and you can give the method a meaningful name to help the next developer trying to see what should happen here.

Comment: Yeah i have looked at this for 2 minutes, and its a mess and a perfect case of you need to start again, and make it easy for your self.. Also what @Andrew said

Comment: Well, you can't implicitly convert `"pdfFormat.png"` to a boolean. `Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || "pdfFormat.png"` **does not ask** "is `Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))` equal to `"jpgFormat.png"` or `"pdfFormat.png"`.

Comment: Your error is here: Check the conditional operator
Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || "pdfFormat.png"
When it should be:
Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || **Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))==**"pdfFormat.png"

Comment: I am trying to add || operator to compare it's "jpgFormat.png" || pdfFormat.png".

Comment: @Ritesh The part left of `||` is first evaluated to a boolean value (true/false), and then, if it's false, OR'd with "pdfFormat.png", which it can't be because "pdfFormat.png" is a string, not a boolean. Of course, the compiler can determine this problem without running the application, hence the message.

Comment: @Ritesh that's not how the `||` operator works. You'd need to do `Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="pdfFormat.png"`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is string in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501194/is-string-in-array)

Answer (score 2):

The offending part is this:

```
Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || "pdfFormat.png"
```

this is *not* the way to check whether "Eval("ImagePath")" is either "jpgFormat" or "pdfFormat". You would need something like

```
Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || Eval("ImagePath"))=="pdfFormat.png"
```

Answer (score 1):

you are having error here

```
 Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || "pdfFormat.png" ? ----
```

the code `Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png"` give a boolean value and you are comparing it with a string value `"pdfFormat.png"`.

Try

```
  (Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="jpgFormat.png" || Convert.ToString(Eval("ImagePath"))=="pdfFormat.png") ?  ------
```