# Compare string array to "FileInfo / GetFiles"

Tags: c#, arrays, compare, getfiles

I have a `string` array that contains all the "*Important files*" names that I want to keep in a folder. The folder contains txts like "spam.txt", or such, aswell as 1 file named "vital.txt"

**The goal would be to move all the other files except important ones to another folder**.

This is what I would do :

```
string[] importantFiles = { "vital.txt", "primordial.dll" };

// with currentDir.GetFiles correctly set
foreach (FileInfo fileScanner in currentDir.GetFiles()) 
{
   foreach (string s in importantFiles)
   {
      // Without the "!", works normally, returns matching files
      if (!fileScanner.Name.Equals(s))
      {
           MessageBox.Show(
             "This is SUPPOSED to be a non matching file : " + fileScanner.Name);
      }
      else // nothing
```

The problem I'm facing with every method I've tried is to "reverse" the matching process. Finding matching file is ok, but filtering the bad one seems impossible to me.

Comment: Here is LINQ example: `var filesToMove = currentDir.GetFiles().Select(fi => fi.Name).Except(importantFiles).ToList();`

Comment: String can't be equal to *all* entries at the same time... so [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501194/is-string-in-array) shows correct version of the code you tried to write in the question and plenty of variants that are shorter in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's move all the files except important, as you've described:

```
using System.IO;

...

// HashSet is better collection than array for your task:
//   1. It's faster on Contains operation: O(1) vs O(N)
//   2. It's more convenient - we can provide a comparer
HashSet<string> importantFiles = new HashSet<string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
  "vital.txt", "primordial.dll" 
};

//TODO: Put the right directory names here
foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\MyDirectory")) {
  if (!importantFiles.Contains(Path.GetFileName(file)))
    File.Move(file, Path.Combine(@"c:\MyDirectoryForSpam", Path.GetFileName(file)));
}
```

Comment: Everything works correctly !Thanks a ton for everyone answer, really helps out a lot. I'll be sure to learn that by heart. Have a great day !